# Null data with Core Bluetooth with iOS 8

Tags: ios, iphone, core-bluetooth

I'm working for the first time with Core Bluetooth and iOS 8.1.1 and I'm having problems just in the first steps of [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/52080/introduction-core-bluetooth-building-heart-rate-monitor).

This is what I'm doing:

- I create the centralManager > OK
- centralManagerDidUpdateState is called with state CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn > OK
- I call scanForPeripheralsWithServices (I called this just after creating my central manager but my code didn't detect any devices. Here in several posts of Stackoverflow I read that with iOS 8 I had to call this after the PowerOn is received. Now it's ok) > OK
- didDiscoverPeripheral is called but the Peripheral info read is "strange".

I'm launching this code in my iPod 5th generation with iOS 8.1.1. I'm trying to detect my MacBook Pro with OS X 10.9.4 and a Samsung Smart TV.
My iPod Bluetooth settings detect my MacBook and my Samsung Smart TV without problems with their correct names.
My MacBook Bluetooth settings detect my iPod and my Samsung Smart TV without problems with their correct names.

When I run my code this is my log in didDiscoverPeripheral:

```
<Warning>: PERIPHERAL DETECTED WITH  
ID: <__NSConcreteUUID 0x16fca020> 81535702-93F4-69F7-EA61-E5FB28E364D8, 
STATE: 0, 
NAME: (null), 
SERVICES: (null), 
DESCRIPTION: 
{
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
        kCBAdvDataServiceData =     
        {
            "Device Information" = <0704>;
        };
        kCBAdvDataServiceUUIDs =     
        (
            "ADAB3E70-6E7D-4601-BDA2-BFFAA68956BA"
        );
    }
<Warning>: PERIPHERAL DETECTED WITH  
ID: <__NSConcreteUUID 0x16fdb7b0> 77124A38-7185-36F7-F587-FFB60D8478E7, 
STATE: 0, 
NAME: (null), 
SERVICES: (null), 
DESCRIPTION: 
{
        kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
}
```

I didn't receive any name.
In detail, this is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central
{
    if ([central state] == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn)
    {
        //NSArray *services = @[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERVICE_1_UUID]];
        // By the moment I'm looking for all devices
        NSDictionary *options = @{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey: @YES};
        [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
    }
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)periph advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"PERIPHERAL DETECTED WITH ID: %@, STATE: %d, NAME: %@, SERVICES: %@, DESCRIPTION: %@",
      [periph identifier],
      [periph state],
      [periph name],
      [periph services],
      [advertisementData description]);
    NSString *name = [advertisementData objectForKey:CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey];
    if ([name length] > 0)
    {
        // I store all periphs detected, show them in a TableView so the user can select the one to connect. 
    }
}
```

So, is there any problem with my code and iOS 8? How could I get the information about the peripherals?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code or the output. There is no service information in the advertising data. You should call `discoverServices` on the `CBPeripheral` to see of the devices have any services that aren't advertised.

Comment: Hi Paulw11! I could understand that the output is ok, but then, why my iPod bluetooth settings shows the name of my SmartTV and my MacBookPro and my app can not get any info related with their names? I guessed that both my app and my Bluetooth settings would receive the same packages.

Comment: Bluetooth settings shows Bluetooth 2.1/3.0 devices, not BLE devices/services

Comment: That must be what is confusing me. I thought that my Macbook Pro has a BLE because I bought it 2 months ago.

Comment: It does have BLE but unless you are running an application that is advertising a BLE service there won't be any services to discover

Comment: Auch! You are right! I will download LightBlue app in my iPad and I'll try again! Thank you very much!

Comment: Just to confirm you were right, I just needed a peripheral running services. Thank you very much!